# How/Where to set limits to avoid error container running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I know this type of question has been addressed in a few posts, but I cannot find an answer the provides the specific "how" or "where"

I am using CDH5.2, running an oozie workflow that executes a shell command. Each time I run it, nodemanager kills the job with the error:

`Container [pid=6757,containerID=container_1424206993158_0001_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container`

Here are the relevant properties I have in my config files. I have clearly missed something though, so I am seeking direction on where specifically this setting must reside.

yarn-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>8196</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>8196</value>
  </property>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
 <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>8196</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3072m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx6144m</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Are you using Cloudera Manager?

Comment: no cloudera manager, just editing configs under /etc manually. Though if you know where it would be in CM I'll checkpoint the VM and try it there.

Comment: In CM these settings are under YARN > Configuration > [Gateway | ResourceManager | NodeManager] > Resource Management. Remember to restart the service and deploy client configurations (use the Actions button on the Configuration screen) after saving changes.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I'll incur the extra overhead from CM if it means I can set  the necessary configuration. If you post this as the answer, I'll accept & close it out.

Comment: Which OS are you using ?  have you tried setting yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled to false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloudera Manager 5 you can modify these YARN resource settings in:

```
YARN > Configuration > Gateway > Resource Management
YARN > Configuration > ResourceManager > Resource Management
YARN > Configuration > NodeManager > Resource Management
```

Remember to restart the service and deploy client configurations (use the Actions button on the Configuration screen) after saving changes.

Comment: Cloudera Manager was causing a few problems (services failing to start, halting, etc so rolled back just prior to it, Someone pointed me towards the ozzie job properties, so I added these to it's xml, which also worked: <property> 
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name> 
    <value>4096</value> 
  </property> 
 <property> 
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts</name> 
    <value>-Xmx3072m</value> 
  </property>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it increasing two memory assignment at:

```
YARN / Configuration / CATEGORY / Resource Management:
```

**Map Task Memory:**

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
```

**Reduce Task Memory:**

```
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```